# CJK font error with xelatex

Tags: fonts, xetex, texlive

I am using the Texlive version 2015.

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex 2019.8.4)  26 SEP 2019 18:12
```

I am using the below code to get CJK for pdflatex and xelatex.

```
  \usepackage{iftex,ifxetex} 
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{xeCJK}
    \newenvironment{CJKlang}{}{}  
  \else
    \usepackage{CJKutf8}
    \newenvironment{CJKlang}{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}}{\end{CJK}}
  \fi
```

pdflatex is working fine, but while running xelatex I am getting error like this

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "FandolSong-Bold" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
```

Also generated a missfonts.log file with below content

```
mktextfm FandolSong-Regular/OT
mktextfm FandolSong-Regular/OT
mktextfm FandolKai/OT
mktextfm FandolKai/B/OT
mktextfm FandolSong-Bold/OT
mktextfm FandolSong-Bold/I/OT
........
```

Fonts are available in my system.

Why it is not working for xelatex.

Result of `dpkg -l texlive-lang-chinese latex-cjk-*`

```
un latex-cjk-chinese               <none> <none> (no description available)
un latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bkai00 <none> <none> (no description available)
un latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bsmi00 <none> <none> (no description available)
un latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gbsn00 <none> <none> (no description available)
un latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gkai00 <none> <none> (no description available)
un latex-cjk-japanese-wadalab      <none> <none> (no description available)
un latex-cjk-thai                  <none> <none> (no description available)
```

Comment: Do you have `texlive-lang-chinese` installed? BTW, you really should update your TeX installation.

Comment: Ok. Then how it works in pdflatex

Comment: Maybe because you have the necessary `latex-cjk-*` installed. Do you want to answer my question?

Comment: How to check `texlive-lang-chinese` is installed or not?

Comment: Post the output of `dpkg -l texlive-lang-chinese latex-cjk-*`.

Comment: un latex-cjk-chinese               <none> <none> (no description available)
un latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bkai00 <none> <none> (no description available)
un latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bsmi00 <none> <none> (no description available)
un latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gbsn00 <none> <none> (no description available)
un latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gkai00 <none> <none> (no description available)
un latex-cjk-japanese-wadalab      <none> <none> (no description available)
un latex-cjk-thai                  <none> <none> (no description available)

Comment: It would be better to [edit] your question when you have additional information. Anyway `sudo apt-get install texlive-lang-chinese` might help.

Comment: Any chance for an update from TeXLive2015 to TeXLive2019?

Comment: Actually, it is not in my system (My friends system). He is in the middle of something.